# How to set value of related entities(objects)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa

I have two entity that have a relation,The relationship works fine, but how can I set value from one object to another in controller.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "material_manu_calculator")
public class MaterialManuCalcu {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "no")
private int no;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
private OrderProductManu orderProductManu;

 //.....getters and setters and constructors}
```

Below is the second Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders_products_manu")
public class OrderProductManu {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "order_id")
private int orderManuId;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "orderProductManu")
private List<MaterialManuCalcu> materialCalcu = new ArrayList<>();

 //.....getters and setters and constructors}
```

below is the Repository

```
   @Repository
   @Transactional
   public interface OrderProductManuRepository extends JpaRepository <OrderProductManu, Integer> {

   @Query(value  ="SELECT *FROM orders_products_manu  WHERE orders_products_manu.order_id =?", nativeQuery = true)
   public OrderProductManu getOrderProductById(int id);
   }
```

I want to set the value of MaterilaManuCalcu in controller as below

```
@Controller
public class ProductsController {
@Autowired
private OrderProductManuRepository orderRepo;

   OrderProductManu orderProduct = orderRepo.getOrderProductById(1);

   MaterialManuCalcu manCalc = new MaterialManuCalcu();
   manCalc.setOrderProductManu(orderProduct.getOrderManuId()); 
   // I get the error says: 
   //    The method setOrderProductManu(OrderProductManu) in 
   //    the type MaterialManuCalcu is not applicable for the arguments (int)
```

Update: **Constructors**

```
    public MaterialManuCalcu(int no, int amountOrdered, int amountAvailable, int amountWillRemain,
        MaterialManu materialmanu, OrderProductManu orderProductManu) {
    this.no = no;
    this.amountOrdered = amountOrdered;
    this.amountAvailable = amountAvailable;
    this.amountWillRemain = amountWillRemain;
    this.materialmanu = materialmanu;
    this.orderProductManu = orderProductManu;
}
```

Another one

```
public OrderProductManu(int orderManuId, String customerName, int amountOrderedManu, String dateOrdered, Users users,
ProductsManu productsManu) {
this.orderManuId = orderManuId;
this.customerName = customerName;
this.amountOrderedManu = amountOrderedManu;
this.dateOrdered = dateOrdered;
this.users = users;
this.productsManu = productsManu;
}
```

Update:Showing how both entities are created

For :  **OrderProductManu**

```
   OrderProductManu orderProduct = new OrderProductManu();
   orderProduct.setDateOrdered("2021-04-14");
   orderProduct.setAmountOrderedManu(platenum);
   orderProduct.setCustomerName("Wapili Mteja");
   orderProduct.setUsers(userMoja.get(0));
   orderProduct.setProductsManu(typeofProduct);
   orderProductManus.setOrderManuId(007);//this is the value that I want to set inside 
   //MateriaManCalcu entity for property setOrderProductManu
   //You can check the relationship above
```

For:  **MaterialManuCalcu**

```
   MaterialManuCalcu manCalc = new MaterialManuCalcu();
   manCalc.setAmountAvailable(availableSheets);
   manCalc.setAmountOrdered(sheetsNum);
   manCalc.setAmountWillRemain(sheetWillRemain);
   manCalc.setMaterialmanu(materialSheet);
   manCalc.setOrderProductManu(orderProduct);//doing this the whole object of 
   //orderProduct entity goes inside a one column in our MatrialManuCalcuof entity
```

Table:**material_manu_calculator**
[image]

How should I do this correctly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to set id of orderProduct which is returned by calling orderProduct.getOrderManuId() of type `int` to variable of type `OrderProductManu`.
Just pass your orderProduct like this `manCalc.setOrderProductManu(orderProduct)`

Comment: the above works, but the problem is that both entities have more attributes as shown in the added constructors. So when i set as you suggest the value that goes to the database are like this :  **OrderProductManu [amountOrderedManu=67.0, customerName=Wapili Mteja, dateOrdered=2021-04-14, orderManuId=10, productsManu=ProductsManu [productManuId=1, productManuName=pooltable plate], users=Users [userId=1, userName=Dada Lydia]]** . while I try to send only the  **orderManuId=10**

Comment: with thymealf engine inside html I could successfull perfom it this like : `${orderProduct.orderManuId}` , Unfortunately my scenario for now I need to do it inside controller not html.

Comment: I don't get what exatcly you want to do in controller. If you want to save new MaterialManuCalcu entity, the above solution will work correctly. Or do you mean anything else?

Comment: Yes I want to save one attribute `orderManuId=10` from object `OrderProductManu` which also has many attributes to the new MaterialManuCalcu object but not all attributes. As suggested if I do `manCalc.setOrderProductManu(orderProduct)` all the attributes of object `orderProduct`are set while I only need one attribute  `orderManuId=10` . How do I perfom this without get type missmatch. Thanks in advance @Looken

Comment: If you really want just to save MaterialManuCalc entity to database, setting `manCalc.setOrderProductManu(orderProduct)` will set to new record value material_manu_calculator.order_id = 10. Also, in your case i don't understand how you got orderManuId is 10, because it should be the same value as you pass in this method of repository `getOrderProductById(int id)`. order_id in database is the same as orderManuId in your entity class

Comment: The database has table for `MaterialManuCalc` entities include one column with the foreign key for `OrderProductManu` entity for property `orderManuId`. I will update the code to display both entities with it's corresponding properties

Comment: How does look your table "material_manu_calculator"in db? what columns does it have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231160/discussion-between-gabriel-rogath-and-looken).